# Brezis' Functional Analysis: the triplet $V \subset H \subset V^*$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, dual-spaces

I'm reading about Gelfand triple from Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigged_Hilbert_space?useskin=vector#Formal_definition_(Gelfand_triple)) and from Brezis' *Functional Analysis*. Could you confirm if my below understanding is fine?

---

Let $(H, \langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle_H)$ be a Hilbert space and $|\cdot|$ its induced norm. Let $V$ be a dense linear subspace of $(H, \langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle_H)$. Assume that the vector space $V$ has its own norm $[ \cdot ]$ such that $(V, [\cdot])$ is a Banach space. We assume that the (linear) inclusion map $i: (V, [\cdot]) \to (H, |\cdot|), v \mapsto v$ is continuous. Let $(V^*, [\![ \cdot ]\!])$ be the dual space of $(V, [\cdot])$. Let $(H^*, \|\cdot\|)$ be the dual space of $(H, |\cdot|)$. Let $i^*:(H^*, \|\cdot\|) \to (V^*, [\![ \cdot ]\!])$ be the adjoint operator of $i$. Then
$$
i^* (\varphi ) = \varphi \restriction V
\quad \forall \varphi \in H^*.
$$

It follows from $V$ is dense in $(H, \langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle_H)$ that $i^*$ is injective. It follows from $i$ is continuous that $i^*$ is continuous. If $(V, [\cdot])$ is reflexive, then $\operatorname{im } i^*$ is dense in $(V^*, [\![ \cdot ]\!])$. By Riesz representation theorem, there is a canonical isometric isomorphism $j:H \to H^*$. Then we write
$$
V \overset{i}{\hookrightarrow} H \overset{j}{\cong} H^* \overset{i^*}{\hookrightarrow} V^*.
$$

The inner product $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle_H$ is compatible with the dual pairing $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{V^*, V}$, i.e.,
$$
\langle u, v \rangle_H = \langle i^* \circ j (u), v \rangle_{V^*, V}
\quad \forall u \in H, v \in V.
$$

Assume now that the norm $[\cdot]$ of $V$ is induced by an inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_V$. By Riesz representation theorem, there is a canonical isometric isomorphism $\ell:V \to V^*$. It is generally **not** true that
$$
\ell = i^* \circ j \circ i.
$$

Comment: It's difficult to see what you're asking. There's just a bunch of text, and we can't see the original writing of the author. I would call $i^\ast$ the *transpose* to avoid confusion with the notion of adjoint operator but otherwise what you've written seems to make sense

Comment: @FShrike Indeed, I intended that $i^*$ is the adjoint operator of $i$. I took that information from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigged_Hilbert_space?useskin=vector#Formal_definition_(Gelfand_triple)) Wikipedia page.

Comment: @FShrike I don't know much about the transpose operator, but I have proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4680136/the-adjoint-operator-of-the-inclusion-map) that $(H^*, \|\cdot\|) \to (V^*, [\![ \cdot ]\!]), \varphi \mapsto \varphi \restriction V$ is the adjoint operator of $i$.

Comment: I'm just being silly. I forgot that the concept of "transpose operator" specialises to give you the adjoint operator when dealing with the canonical $H\cong H^\ast$

Comment: seem right what you write, in particular $l \ne i^* j i$. Think of $V =H^1$, $H=L^2$.  Then the dual pairing between $V,V^*$ is induced by the inner product of $L^2$ not be the inner product of $H^1$.

Comment: @daw Thank you so much for your verification!